# Facebook like button - discrepancy between render of old and new design

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've rendered a Facebook Like button on blog posts of a Wordpress theme [using the Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button), including the following attributes:

```
data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false"
```

As you may know [Facebook changed the design of this button](http://www.theverge.com/2016/6/28/12046822/facebook-like-button-redesign) during summer 2016.

I created a share bar, where I have mimicked the same button design for other social media platforms, and render the Facebook like button at the end of the bar:

[image: Render of new designed Facebook like button]

Interestingly though: the client submitted a bug to say that the 'Facebook Like' didn't fit alongside the other buttons. On examination, I realised that at their location it renders the old design:

[image: Render of old design Facebook like button]

It seems that when logged out of Facebook, it renders the old design. However for some user when logged in it still renders the old design too.

Anyone know if the new design can be forced, else how this can be remedied?

Comment: Can you check the generated HTML on your page if the configured attributes (like `data-layout`) are the same in both cases?

Comment: Hey @FabianH. yes they are.

Comment: Did you use the same browser instance for both cases? Can you reproduce the error in a JSfiddle?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem recently, realizing that only when the user is logged in we have the new design being applied. In [contact with Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/244224226015213/), that's what they said:

> Thanks for reaching out! It's normal that when new feature is
>   launching, different user will probably see different things (old
>   design vs new design). Sorry to say that developer cannot customize
>   which design is showed to user. I think the new design shouldn't be an
>   issue to your website because the size of the component is not
>   changed. If you need more information, please let me know.

Unfortunately, it's not a thing customizable, yet. The option is: wait until they release it for all situations.